# CSS - display:table with display:flex as sub-child div

Tags: css, flexbox, css-tables

I have a div with `display:table;`. In that div, I have 2 divs. 1 div has a `width:100%`, div2 has `width:320px`

In div1 I have multiple rows, with each row having 3 divs max (some have 1 or 2). I am using `display:flex; justify-content:space-around;` to nicely align the rows and their divs vertically and horizontally.

The problem here is that when I use `display:flex;`, all the content of div2 is pushed down below that last row. That is weird since div1 and div2 are next to eachother and the content of div1 is not interfering with div2.

Visual example of problem:

```
====================================
=        div1          =    div2   =
====================================
=         +++          =           =
=         +++          =           =
=                      =           =
=    +++  +++  +++     =           =
=    +++  +++  +++     =           =
=                      =           =
=    +++  +++  +++     =           =
=    +++  +++  +++     =           =
=                      =  content  =
=                      =     of    =
=                      =    div2   =
=                      =   starts  =
=                      =    here   =
====================================

each ++ is a div inside a row
     ++
```

Is there anyway I can get this done properly? Having div1 and div2 next to eachother, while div1 content is using `display:flex; justify-content:space-around;` and div2 content starts at top and is not being pushed down by div1 content.

EDIT:
Here is my jsFiddle, to show the error. https://jsfiddle.net/3uss54pc/

EDIT 2:
I tried removing the `display:flex` and instead use `float:left;` on the `.row-div` and add a `clear:both;` at the and of each `.row`, but the content of div2 is still being pushed downwards.

I guess this is not a problem with the `display:flex;`, but rather a problem with the structure of my `display:table;`??

Comment: If you can use Bootstrap then you should use that. It will help you

Comment: Please add a starting point by providing a JSFiddle or CodePen. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Ankit Bootstrap is not *always* the answer, keep in mind that Bootstrap is  somewhat overpowered to achieve want the questioner wants.

Comment: @Roy It was just an advice I am pretty sure that OP wants responsiveness without writing media queries in CSS and cases like this.

Comment: @Ankit An advice would actually make sense, now you're asking to build a castle to park your lawn mower.

Comment: 100% + 320px is for a start more than 100% :) , then, what about your structure and the css you really tried ?

Comment: Thank you all, I added the jsfiddle. And I am not using Bootstrap because I did not think that could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by removing the `flex` elements and use a `display:table` and `display:table-cell;` instead. This way the div2 content is shown at the right place.